# Создание картинки метки "на лету" при ее появлении из кластера

Tags: ios, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Добавляю ка карту 3000 меток используя кластеризатор. Кластеры добавляются, все ок.

Добавляю таким образом:

```
clusterizedPlacemarkCollection.addPlacemarks(with: points,
                                 image: UIImage(named: "mapMarker")!,
                                 style: YMKIconStyle())
    
clusterizedPlacemarkCollection.clusterPlacemarks(withClusterRadius: 60, minZoom: 15)
```

Но так для всех меток устанавливается одна и та же картинка. Мне же нужно для каждой метки чуть ли не уникальную картинку выставлять. Картинки самих меток "сложные", формируются из нескольких картинок и текста, для каждой метки - своя картинка. Создавать сразу и присваивать 3000 картинок меткам не вариант - слишком трудозатратная операция.

В Google.Maps есть например метод `renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker)`, который позволяет получать событие когда должна отобразиться метка, и в этом методе создать и присвоить нужную картинку. В SDK Яндекс.Карт такого найти не могу, это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

В MapKit для ios такой возможности нет.

Можно попробовать уменьшить количество уникальных картинок с помощью [CompositeIcon](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/ios-ref/full/Classes/YMKCompositeIcon-docpage/). Это позволит собрать составную иконку из нескольких слоев. Но это, конечно, имеет смысл делать только если количество разных составных частей из которых состоят иконки заметно меньше, чем число иконок.